# Azure Function log4net

Tags: function, azure, azure-functions, log4net

I'm using log4net in Azure Function instead of default Tracewriter. After much headache, I'm gottent the log file to work in class library and I can log to file. However the logging in the console is not shown in local debug deployment.

How should I redirect the Azure Function logging in log4net?

Comment: Hi there Robin! How are you configuring log4net? Can you show us some code please?

Comment: which part are you having problems with?

Comment: Try serilog with Azure functions, fast and stable

Comment: Why you don't use App Insights?

Comment: Prefer a solution that is not vendor lock in